# passing array from one class to another without segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have class `A` where array is:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *tempClientNameArray;
```

I want to get the value of `tempClientNameArray` in class `B`. And, I'm doing like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    A *obj = [[A alloc]init];
    obj.view;
    clientlists =  obj.tempClientNameArray;
}
```

In this way I'm not getting value of `tempClientNameArray`.

Note: I need to assign `tempClientNameArray` to `NSMutableArray` `clientlists`

What I'm doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: And where in class `A` tempClientNameArray is supposed to be filed up?

Comment: You cant get data like this. While switch A to B pass the array..

Comment: What's the value you are getting in obj.tempClientNameArray? I think obj.tempClientNameArray value also nil

Comment: @Ossir, Thanks for your Hints..Got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Do this to pass data from A to B..Put this code in A implementation file to switch A to B..

```
B *b = [[B alloc]init];
b.clientlists = tempClientNameArray;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
```

if you not use navigationController to switch do below code

```
B *b = [[B alloc]init];
b.clientlists = tempClientNameArray;
[self presentViewController:b animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I hope this will be helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

By doing this -

```
clientlists =  obj.tempClientNameArray;// wrong approach
```

You are storing address reference to an array.

**This what you have to do.**

```
NSMutableArray * clientlists =[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:obj.tempClientNameArray];
```